# Switching to mobile site in MVC4

Tags: redirect, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to write an MVC4 site that will perform browser detection and switch accordingly to support a variety of mobile devices. I've already picked out a browser detection library. To keep load low I want to perform browser detection only once, and rewrite URLs accordingly, e.g. mydomain.com/Home => mydomain.com/iOS/Home. This would also allow manually switching to the desktop version.

What's the best way to achieve this? A redirect after the detection code? Just change all future links generated somehow? Other?

Answer (score 1):

I once did the detection in the Global.asax `BeginRequest` event. The request was redirected to a `MobileController` that was responsible for the entire mobile website. Nowadays I use adaptive/responsive design, which is in my opinion a much better approach.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I'm aiming to mostly do that, e.g. keep the majority of controllers and views the same, but have conditional logic to prevent any heavy-weight desktop-only content being sent to mobiles due to bandwidth considerations. I'm also not clear on how to make themes match the mobile platform, e.g. iOS devices get iOS styles.

Comment: Take a look at http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/ to load for example movies or ajax content on large screen widths only.